# How do I change a label in GTK while the program is running; from a seperate thread

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I am building a multi-threaded application which will display weather data and update automatically in C. I got the weather data to refresh and loaded into variables. I am having trouble changing values on my program mid-run. When I use

```
gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(wsrc->text2), wsrc->deg);
```

I get

```
(out:7604): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_label_set_text: assertion `GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
```

How do I do this. The call is from a separate thread from main that loops to renew weather data.

Do I use signals to create a trigger to renew weather data. Looking for advice :)

Comment: [Read this post](http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness). Carefully, it's not 100% intuitive (and for some strange reason even worse documented now than it used to be).

Comment: @unwind There may be situations where you want to play with gdk thread locks. In my opinion this is definitely not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call GTK+ methods from outside it's main thread, period. I know there are workarounds, but 99.99% of the time you really do not want to do it.

What you should do instead is this:

```
/* in your other thread do this: it will make sure update_text2 will be called in
   GTK+ main thread */
g_main_context_invoke (NULL, update_text2, wsrc);

static gboolean update_text2 (gpointer userdata)
{
    my_obj* wsrc = (my_obj*) userdata;
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(wsrc->text2), wsrc->deg);
    return G_SOURCE_REMOVE;
}
```

I didn't test that code, and don't know the type of your wsrc pointer but I'm sure you get the drift.

Comment: suggestion: replace the "FALSE" return value with "G_SOURCE_REMOVE". it makes it slightly more readable.

Comment: also, g_main_context_invoke() is probably better than g_idle_add() in terms of readability - even if they amount pretty much to the same thing in case of a default main context.

Comment: @ebassi cheers (I was like "G_SOURCE_REMOVE? No-one has a GLib that recent" -- and checking reveals it's about 1.5 years old already...).

Comment: even LTS releases have it, I bet. well, maybe not Debian... ;-)